# Extracting Specific files from large zip thru python

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have a big zip with 300.000+ files in with all directories and subdirectories
On the other hand, I have a list of 1200 files I need to extract from the zip.
This list has the dir path and file name in it as one (see exp)
Exp:
/var/db/bla/file.ext

At this moment, I use the following code to search and extract the files from the zip (with keeping the timestamp). It works, but it's really slow. Is there a better way? Now it's reading all the files from the zip, and if it's a match, it extracts it.
Is there maybe a way to give the file location (thru the list) directly and extract it without making a list of all the files in it?

```
files = df2.drop_duplicates().drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
pbar_max = (len(files))
pbar = tqdm(total=int(pbar_max))

##
for count, i in enumerate(files):

    for item in (f for f in zip_file.filelist if i in f.filename):

        e = item.date_time
        gettime = "%s/%s/%s %s:%s" % (e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4])

        #print(item.filename)
        zip_file.extract(item.filename, directory)
        filep = directory + item.filename
        timearry = time.mktime(time.strptime(gettime, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'))
        os.utime(filep, (timearry, timearry))

        pbar.update(1)



pbar.close()
```

Hope somebody has a clever Idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance your script is spending most of the time in `zip_file.extract`, so there may not be much you can do. You would need to run the script through a profiler to know for sure.

That said, you may be able to make things better by restructuring the two loops. At the moment you the outer loop is iterating through `zip_file.filelist` 1600 times. That outer loop can be eliminated completely, like this

```
# store the file list as a set
files = set( df2.drop_duplicates().drop_duplicates().values.tolist() )

# now only have to iterate the zip once
for item in (f for f in zip_file.zipinfo if f.filename in files):
    e = item.date_time
    gettime = "%s/%s/%s %s:%s" % (e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4])

    #print(item.filename)
    zip_file.extract(item.filename, directory)
    filep = directory + item.filename
    timearry = time.mktime(time.strptime(gettime, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'))
    os.utime(filep, (timearry, timearry))

    pbar.update(1)
```

You will need to test the code to see if that makes much difference.

**[EDIT]**

Here is a worked example

First create a zip file

```
$ touch alpha beta gamma delta
$ zip test.zip alpha beta gamma delta
updating: alpha (stored 0%)
updating: beta (stored 0%)
updating: gamma (stored 0%)
updating: delta (stored 0%)
```

Now walk through the zip file

```
import zipfile

# want to match against these three names
files = { 'alpha', 'gamma', 'omega' }

with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip') as zip_file:
    for item in (f for f in zip_file.filelist if f.filename in files):
        print(item.filename)
```

outputs

```
alpha
gamma
```

Note that this will only work if you know the exact filename in the zip file you match against. Your code was doing a substring match.

Comment: i cant get your code to work, it looks like the "if f.filename in files" wont work.
Have a idea how to fix it?